# Add line to the top of a file and be idempotent

Tags: bash, shell

How, in shell script, add a line to the beginning of a file and be idempotent (multiple runs do the change only once)?

I tried [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/comments/1jvk9j/idempotent_append_line_to_file/) solution but it is for the end of the file

Comment: Get the first line of the file into a variable. Check if it contains what you want to add. If not, add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gnu awk` you can do:

```
awk -i inplace -v line='foo bar' 'NR==1 && $0 != line{print line} 1' file
```

This will insert `fpo bar` in 1st line only if file doesn't start with `foo bar` line.

If you don't have `gnu-awk` then use:

```
awk -v s='foo bar' 'NR==1 && $0!=s{print s} 1' file > _tmp_ && mv _tmp_ file
```